# PDO: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: pdo, token

I've been breaking my head over the following.

What you can see below is the result of a dynamically build INSERT together with its BINDS. The column names and tokens are being pulled from the table. I do not know them in advance. So I use build in functions to know what they are. The values are posted to me via a form. I put both together using an associative array which I use to build the INSERT command.

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 0
    [datum] => 1968-05-13 16:58:02
    [titel] => test 369
    [categorie] => catEGORIE
    [tekst] => tekst
    [zichtbaar_bijlage] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_1] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_2] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_3] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_4] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_5] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_6] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_7] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_8] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_9] => 1
    [zichtbaar_foto_10] => 1
    [bijlage] => verkeersbord.jpg
    [foto_1] => hummel.jpg
    [foto_2] => reinoutgerolf.jpg
    [foto_3] => hummel.jpg
    [foto_4] => verkeersbord.jpg
    [foto_5] => verkeersbord.jpg
    [foto_6] => 20140511vlaggen.jpg
    [foto_7] => verkeersbord.jpg
    [foto_8] => 20140511vlaggen.jpg
    [foto_9] => verkeersbord.jpg
    [foto_10] => 50-euro-1024x545.jpg
)
```

A dump of the INSERT command and the BINDS looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_DB.some_table (NIE_id, NIE_datum, NIE_titel, NIE_categorie, NIE_tekst, NIE_zichtbaar_bijlage, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_1, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_2, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_3, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_4, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_5, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_6, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_7, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_8, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_9, NIE_zichtbaar_foto_10, NIE_bijlage, NIE_foto_1, NIE_foto_2, NIE_foto_3, NIE_foto_4, NIE_foto_5, NIE_foto_6, NIE_foto_7, NIE_foto_8, NIE_foto_9, NIE_foto_10) VALUES (:id, :datum, :titel, :categorie, :tekst, :zichtbaar_bijlage, :zichtbaar_foto_1, :zichtbaar_foto_2, :zichtbaar_foto_3, :zichtbaar_foto_4, :zichtbaar_foto_5, :zichtbaar_foto_6, :zichtbaar_foto_7, :zichtbaar_foto_8, :zichtbaar_foto_9, :zichtbaar_foto_10, :bijlage, :foto_1, :foto_2, :foto_3, :foto_4, :foto_5, :foto_6, :foto_7, :foto_8, :foto_9, :foto_10)
$STH3->bindValue(':id', 0);
$STH3->bindValue(':datum', 1968-05-13 16:58:02);
$STH3->bindParam(':titel', test 369, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':categorie', catEGORIE, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':tekst', tekst, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_bijlage', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_1', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_2', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_3', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_4', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_5', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_6', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_7', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_8', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_9', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':zichtbaar_foto_10', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':bijlage', verkeersbord.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_1', hummel.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_2', reinoutgerolf.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_3', hummel.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_4', verkeersbord.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_5', verkeersbord.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_6', 20140511vlaggen.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_7', verkeersbord.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_8', 20140511vlaggen.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_9', verkeersbord.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH3->bindParam(':foto_10', 50-euro-1024x545.jpg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The INSERT command is generated by the following:

```
$command = "INSERT INTO $_SESSION[database].$table ($fields) VALUES ($arguments)";
            echo $command;
            $STH3 = $DBH->prepare($command);


            foreach($binds_array as $key => $value)
                {
                    if ($key == "id")
                        {
                            $STH3->bindValue(':id', 0);
                            echo "<br>--- STH3->bindValue(':id', 0);<br>";
                        }
                        elseif ($key == "datum")
                        {
                            $STH3->bindValue(':$key', $value);
                            echo "--- STH3->bindValue(':$key', $value);<br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $STH3->bindParam(':$key', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            echo "--- STH3->bindParam(':$key', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);<br>";
                        };
                };
```

For some reason this is resulting in an error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

I've been reading up on whatever I could find on this problem but I'm not able to pinpoint the problem. As far as I can see (but I might be blind) the number of tokens and the number of variables is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the code, given I understood it correctly, seems fine. There is however one little problem in your code, namely your `bindValue`s.

Both `$STH3->bindValue(':$key', $value);` and `$STH3->bindParam(':$key', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);` suffer from the same problem: `$key` is enclosed in single quotes, which causes the variable not te be evaluated, but to be interpreted as is (as a string).

For variables inside a string  to be evaluated in PHP, they need to be in **double quotes**, so the two lines of code above must become `$STH3->bindValue(":$key", $value);` and `$STH3->bindParam(":$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);`.

Comment: This was indeed part of the problem. But I shortened the code even more by executing an array.

Answer (score 0):

@PLPeeters: you solved part of the problem. Many thanks for that! As mentioned in my comment to your answer I shortened the code even more to achieve more flexibility.

```
foreach($binds_array as $key => $value)
    {
    $arguments[] .= ":$key";
    };
$arguments = implode(',',$arguments);
```

I deleted a part of the code which was default code to get the columns and put them in $fields.

```
$command_add = "INSERT INTO some_database.some_table ($fields) VALUES ($arguments)";
$STH3 = $DBH->prepare($command_add);
$STH3->execute($binds_array)
```

Comment: Nice job there. Just got one question: are you 100% certain of the safety of what's inside the `$fields` variable and the keys of `$binds_array`? As is, this code is vulnerable to SQL injections, unless you have 100% certainty that what's contained in those variables is safe and always will be.

Comment: Well, I am. But I skipped the part of the code where I check the input. You never know when coworkers try to ... you! ;-)